# Threading with Jira-Python sporadically results in 401 Error

Tags: python, multithreading, jira

I am attempting to query and then display a large number of JIRA tickets using Jira-Python.

Rather than querying individual tickets one at a time, I am creating a thread for each ticket I want to get results from, storing all of the results in a list, then after all results are in, displaying the results in a table.

This works fine for queries of less than about 200 tickets, but any amount larger than that and I start to get 401 errors on only some of the threads, while others go through just fine.

I have no problem with login data and getting small lists of tickets to go through.

Here's what I'm doing in the main Thread after login:

```
jiraTicketLists = self.chunks(self.jiraQueryData, listSize) #Split full list into smaller lists to run in each thread

for jiraTicketList in jiraTicketLists:
    t = threading.Thread(target=jiraFunctions.queryJiraTicket, args=(jiraTicketList, self.jiraFieldList, self))
    t.start()
```

and in the created Thread:

```
def queryJiraTicket(ticketNumberList, attributeList, parent):

    for ticketNumber in ticketNumberList:
        try:
            issue = JIRA.issue(ticketNumber, expand='changelog')

            jiraDict = {}

            for attribute in attributeList:
                jiraAttr = ""

                if attribute == "Summary":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.summary
                elif attribute == "Description":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.description
                elif attribute == "Assignee":
                    try:
                        jiraAttr = issue.fields.assignee.name
                    except:
                        jiraAttr = "Unassigned"
                elif attribute == "Status":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.status
                elif attribute == "Priority":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.priority
                elif attribute == "Type":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.issuetype
                elif attribute == "Labels":
                    jiraAttr = issue.fields.labels
                elif attribute == "Comments":
                    jiraAttr = [comment["body"] for comment in issue.raw['fields']['comment']['comments']]
                elif attribute == "Ticket Number":
                    jiraAttr = issue
                elif attribute == "Transitions":
                    jiraAttr = JIRA.transitions(issue)
                elif attribute == "Changelog":
                    changelog = issue.changelog

                    historyList = []
                    for history in changelog.histories:
                        for item in history.items:
                            historyList.append(history.created)

                    historyList.sort()

                    jiraAttr = historyList

                jiraDict[attribute] = jiraAttr

            if parent != None:
                #Update UI with new ticket data
                parent.ticketList.append(jiraDict)
                parent.ticketNum = parent.ticketNum + 1

                parent.updateProgressBarSignal.emit()

                if parent.ticketNum == parent.numberOfTickets:
                    parent.getJiraTicketData()

    except jira.JIRAError as e:
        print e.status_code, e.text
```

Any idea why I get 401 errors on large lists, but not on small lists?

Comment: Presumably, the JIRA object doesn't channel all the requests through a single connection. Rather it establishes one for each query. You are then hitting a limit set either in JIRA, or more likely on the server, that prevents multiple simultaneous connections from the same host.